# Ternary Operator return values

Tags: java, conditional-operator

`x>5 ? list1.add(something) : list2.add(something);`

Why do I have to take the return value from expressions of ternary operator? I should have the option to ignore the return value.

It's forcing me to take the return value like below

`boolean y = x>5 ? list1.add(something) : list2.add(something);`

Comment: If you're not trying to get a value you shouldn't be using the conditional operator. That's what `if` statements are for.

Comment: Because the intention of people who made Java was for ternary operator to work that way?

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason you can't do `1 + 1;` on its own: because an expression by itself is not a statement (as the actual error message tells you).

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator is part of an expression, which means its purpose is to be evaluated. If you're not trying to get a value you shouldn't be using the conditional operator. That's what `if` statements are for.

Though in this case, it looks like you could achieve the effect you want using:

```
(x > 5 ? list1 : list2).add(something);
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional `?:` operator produces an expression (which means it's a bit of the syntax tree which has a value when it is executed). However, it's not a *statement expression*, meaning you can't just add a `;` to the end of it to make a statement.

Examples of statement expressions are method invocations, constructor invocations, pre/post-increments. These make sense to stand by themselves as a statement, because they have (or can have) side effects. You can take the expression `i++`, add a semicolon `i++;`, and you have a valid, meaningful statement.

Non-statement expressions like addition `1 + 2` don't make sense by themselves. It's a bit like saying "cat and dog": it's not a "whole sentence". A conditional operator makes something like "if rain then cat else dog", which doesn't make much sense either.

If you find yourself wanting to write a conditional expression as a statement, just use an if/else statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

It does not execute because it's an expression not a statement.